# MySQL: Select Where Distinct if 1st entry, not Distinct within query

Tags: mysql

I have a Table containing columns Email, Ip, State, City, TimeStamp, Id

I need to count where Email and IP are distinct, group by State

So when I run a MYSQL query,

```
select State, City ,count(distinct( Email )), count(DISTINCT( IP))
from table
group by Stat, City
```

It gives me distinct of each, but not AND

I need a count of distinct Email && Distinct  IP ; grouped by State, City.

And distincts cant be within the Group, it has to be the 1st instance of EMAIL, and first instance of IP in entire database. So if i expand it, and add a date parameter, even though im selecting a specific date, I still can check whole database for the uniques.

So if i need

```
select state, city, count ( distinct ( IP ) , count ( distinct ( EMAIL )) 
from table
where timestamp > date(2014-12-01)
group by state, city
```

What type of query is this? And how can I accomplish this?

My gut tells me i need to do CONCAT as suggested, but also another select inside. So select whole database distinct ip, then select that specific criteria from the other select.

Comment: Please edit your question.  Your columns are not that difficult to abbreviate as A, B, C and D.  Put it as it is, proper columns and may as well put table name vs just "table".

Comment: I love that you think we might understand this. What's more weird is that some of us probably do (like the individual who up voted)!?!

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. Writing `distinct(b)` is useless.

Comment: Except, with the magic of a standard current DEFAULT mysql, it is a select option. Try it.

Select distinct B; or select count(distinct(b)) .. works.

Comment: Also - I edited this. I do not know why strawberry is being so hostile. Naming of my items is arbitrary. But if it really helps, I need unique IPs and Unique Emails. Vs Unique A and Unique B. 

If you do not know what I am talking about. Try not to throw a fit. Wait for someone who will, or ask for clarity.

Comment: Do you allow JOINs in your query?

Comment: Yes, anything that works is acceptible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We struggled to do this on a production server and found the query required was too resource intensive. So we created a table with an update on first instance the item occurs, then we check for counts with a join like so:

```
select count(a.State) from tablename A
inner join table_update  U
on a.id = u.id
WHERE a.parameters..
and c.first_email = 1
and c.first_ip = 1
```

We couldnt find a single table that wouldnt bring our server down with 400,000 records. Its not a classy answer, but its what we had to use.

Answer (score 0):

This can help a bit to have a "distinct(A && B)"

SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(A,'_',B)),C,D
FROM table
GROUP BY C,D

Comment: Yep. Distinct still ain't a function

Comment: but if that query adds parameters of dates in a WHERE, the distinct is only within the WHERE, and not the database, Correct?

Comment: I think strawberry is throwing a warning on the whole use of parenthesis. select count ( distinct COLUMN ) ; select coun